# Create new window with QTableView from ComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qtableview

this is my first time here and my experience with Qt is about 2 months.

My question is:

I have an ui form which will be the main window and will contain a ComboBox. In this ComboBox, imagine I have two options ( Car1 and Car2 ). What I want to do seems to be very simple. If I select the first option ( Car1 ), there will be a new window, which will contain a table (QTableView) with two columns (“Variable” and “Value” in its headers), and three rows (“Car name”, “Price” and “Power not in the headers, but under the column “Variable”) and under the column “Value” there will be for example “Nissan GTR” , “ 300.000,00 “ and “ 500 “.

Also, the information for filling the table cells will be stored in a header (.h) either in an array, or in a vector.

Does anyone have an idea how can I implement this?

Thank you,
Marcos

Comment: Your question does not appear to be about a specific issue but rather asking for design or implementation advice.  Please clarify a *specific* problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: You can set your own model on the combobox and set your own item view.
See `QComboBox::setModel()` and `QComboBox::setView()`. Try using a table model and a table view. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html for more info.